# What is the difference between instantiating hashmap without angle brackets and with?

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between the following?

`new HashMap();` vs `new HashMap<Integer, String>();`?

I've never used the former or seen it but is there any differences I should know?

Comment: Your second example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one doesnt know what type of data hashmap has. You can have any type of object in this map. Second one specifies what is key and value types for this map. You can only insert those types into map. This approach is called generics.

Answer (score 3):

Following statement will creates a map whose key-value types are `raw`. (java.lang.Object).

```
HashMap map=new HashMap();
```

In second statement, you are specifying type of `Key` and `Value` (Read [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)) .

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It should be `new Hashmap<Integer, String>()`.
2. The first case will use `Object` type for keys as well as values and will return `Object` instances when you retrieve them. In the second case, you are specifying that the keys should be of `Integer` type and the values are of `String` type. So, you should add accordingly and when you retrieve, you'll get `String` object for values and `Integer` object for keys and you will not need a cast as in the previous case.

P.S. I think the reason you should use `Integer` and not `int` is that the type used should be "nullable" if some method needs to return `null`. `int` is not nullable.